# Neo4j - Exclude node from results where it has a specific relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm attempting to a set of nodes (p) where they have a relationship [:INCLUDE] to a specific node (ca) identified by its ID, but I also want to make sure I exclude any (p) node that also has an [:EXCLUDE] relationship to any other (ca) node.

I've tried the below...

```
MATCH (a:CloudApp)-[]-(p:Policy{state: "enabled"})
WHERE (a{id:"All"})-[]-(p) OR (a{id:"b9a97804-0c6b-4d83-8b35-84bda7f8b69c"})-[]-(p)
WITH p,a
MATCH (p)-[]-(pl:Platform {id: "macOS"})
WHERE NOT (p)-[:EXCLUDE_Platform]-(pl)
WITH p,a,pl
RETURN *
```

Which gets me this...

[image]

And then tried to filter it with this...

```
MATCH (a:CloudApp)-[]-(p:Policy{state: "enabled"})
WHERE (a{id:"All"})-[]-(p) OR (a{id:"b9a97804-0c6b-4d83-8b35-84bda7f8b69c"})-[]-(p)
WITH p,a
MATCH (p)-[]-(pl:Platform {id: "macOS"})
WHERE NOT (p)-[:EXCLUDE_Platform]-(pl) AND NOT (p)-[:EXCLUDE_CLOUDAPP]-(a)
WITH p,a,pl
RETURN *
```

But this results in the same 3 (p) nodes and just excludes the (a) node where that relationship exists. I've tried a few variations on the above query and always seem to get the same result...

[image]

I'm guessing that this is because it just excludes that relationship and the node remains because it has another valid relationship. I'm just not sure how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the variable `a` from the condition `NOT (p)-[:EXCLUDE_CLOUDAPP]-(a)` and add a node label, and try this:

```
MATCH (a:CloudApp)-[]-(p:Policy{state: "enabled"})
WHERE (a{id:"All"})-[]-(p) OR (a{id:"b9a97804-0c6b-4d83-8b35-84bda7f8b69c"})-[]-(p)
WITH p,a
MATCH (p)-[]-(pl:Platform {id: "macOS"})
WHERE NOT (p)-[:EXCLUDE_Platform]-(pl) AND NOT (p)-[:EXCLUDE_CLOUDAPP]-(:CloudApp)
WITH p,a,pl
RETURN *
```

This basically checks whether the policy node is not linked to any CloudApp node via exclude relationship.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I solved it was this

```
MATCH (a:CloudApp)-[]-(p:Policy{state: "enabled"})
WHERE (p)-[:EXCLUDE_CLOUDAPP]-(a)
WITH COLLECT(p) as excluded
MATCH (a:CloudApp)-[]-(p:Policy{state: "enabled"})
WHERE (a{id:"All"})-[]-(p:Policy{state: "enabled"})
WITH p,a,excluded
MATCH (p)-[]-(pl:Platform {id: "macOS"})
WHERE NOT (p)-[:EXCLUDE_Platform]-(pl)
WITH COLLECT(p) as included, excluded
RETURN [n IN included WHERE not n IN excluded] as list
```

I found the nodes I didn't want, then the ones I did want and removed the excluded ones from those using the WHERE not n IN part